# iOS: How to use default web view?

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I am using custom webview in iOS for linkedin Auth. I can see google & facebook seems using exactly same view controller interface for their web-view based authentication. but I can't find such view controller.

Is there any webview with defualt interface? Thanks in advance...

**Facebook:**

[image]

**Google:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is a zero-tab modal used by iOS Applications for external authentication. It can look different apps.

This cannot be set to the default Style for a web browser unless the browser is designed that way.

Comment: Google & facebook used exactly same design? Also, these two asking confirmation before presenting the auth modal.